# Searching custom fields in Maniphest (Phabricator)

Tags: phabricator

I set up a custom field in Maniphest as a drop down. It assigns the correct value to each task, but the copy and search function don't work at all.

If I try to search by a value in this field, everything comes up matching all the other search criteria and ignores my custom field.

If I create a similar task, it always defaults back to the first option in the list.

```
{
 "my-comp:task-type": {
    "name": "Type",
    "type": "select",
    "options": {
      "my-comp:bug": "Bug",
      "my-comp:feature": "Feature",
      "my-comp:ui": "UI",
      "my-comp:improve": "Improvement",
      "my-comp:misc": "Misc",
      "my-comp:planning": "Planning"
    },
    "required": true,
    "search": true,
    "copy": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy currently doesn't work: [T8055](https://secure.phabricator.com/T8055).  There doesn't appear to be a workaround offered at this time.

As for the search, what version are you running?  I am running commit [2eab1c1943c511](https://secure.phabricator.com/rP2eab1c1943c511f0df4bb1b9f78dadf45c8ef160) from the stable branch and I am not experiencing the issue.  I also upgraded to [f2b2264e8def0a](https://secure.phabricator.com/rPf2b2264e8def0a69d1431f38c1d202273f95842b) and I still didn't have the issue.  I think you may need to upgrade your version of Phabricator.

Comment: Of course I just needed to upgrade. Just upgraded to f2b2264e8def0a and it is working as it should. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad that helped!